# Run 2 SELECT statements together and separate results in different columns

Tags: sql

I have these 2 `SELECT` statements and I want to query them together and the result should be in separate columns. I can't use `UNION` because it results in only one column. Is there any simple way I can do this? Thank you so much!

```
SELECT value from value_all where domainid='3851504'
SELECT value from value_all where domainid='3580420'
```

Desired Output:

```
value (1) | value (2)
---------------------
a         |    c
b         |    d
```

Comment: What if different number of rows from the SELECTs?

Comment: Tag your DBMS please.

Comment: There must be some kind of relation between the two!?

Answer (score 0):

Try using alias:

```
    SELECT (SELECT value from value_all where domainid='3851504') AS 'value (1)' ,
           (SELECT value from value_all where domainid='3580420') AS 'value (2)'
```

Comment: Note that each SELECT returns more than 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

Use `CROSS JOIN` if you use `SQL Server 2005` or a higher version.

```
SELECT A.Value [Value (1)], B.Value [Value (2)] FROM 
(SELECT value,
row_number() over (order by (select null)) r
 from value_all where domainid='3851504')A
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT value,
row_number() over (order by (select null)) r
 from value_all where domainid='3580420')B
 WHERE A.r = B.r
```

Comment: If selectA returns 2 rows, and selectB also returns 2 rows, will this return 2 rows (or 4)?